# How to exclude scroll indicators while enumerating subviews of a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview, uikit

I'm trying to adjust my `subviews` in a `UIScrollView` subclass, but I don't want to disturb the scroll indicators. There doesn't seem to be any public interface to access these and I want to check if a view is one of the scroll indicators or not (so that I can ignore it).

`UIScrollView.h` declares these two iVars:

```
UIImageView* _verticalScrollIndicator;
UIImageView* _horizontalScrollIndicator;
```

...but I tried the following and got a linker error:

```
for(UIView* v in self.subviews)
{
    // Ignore the scroll-indicator views
    if( (v == _horizontalScrollIndicator) ||
        (v == _verticalScrollIndicator))
    {
        continue;
    }
    // View is one of mine - do stuff to it...
}
```

Apple obviously don't want you messing with these, in which case they should do something clever so that the array returned from `subviews` doesn't include them (come on Apple, it's not that hard!), but until then how can I ignore them?

Answer (score 7):

This ended up being my work-around

```
BOOL showsVerticalScrollIndicator = self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator;
BOOL showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator;

self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

// loop through self.subviews here

self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = showsVerticalScrollIndicator;
self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = showsHorizontalScrollIndicator;
```

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you're in control of the views that you put in the `UIScrollView`. Why not maintain your own array of just those views? That way, you are safe against any future changes in the implementation of UIScrollView.

Comment: I'm writing a UIScrollView subclass, so I am not in control of those other subviews. I tried overriding didAddSubview: and willRemoveSubview: to keep track, but the scroll indicators must be added normally like any other view because they end up calling these too.

Comment: I'd go with @KurtRevis on this one.  Keep your own array, maintain it by overriding addSubview: and removeSubview: (which I don't think OS calls for the scroll indicators).

If you don't want to do that, then a quick and dirty answer with no Apple dependencies is to tag the subviews on addSubview:.  When you enumerate subviews, reject the ones with the tag.  The downside here is that you'll end up spoiling the tags for subclass's users, who might need the tags left alone.

Other solutions I can think of all have dependencies on Apple internals.

Comment: Apple do use addSubView: to add the scroll indicators so this is not viable. Also anything that does want to track subviews should also keep track in the insertSubview:* methods.

Answer (score 1):

i'm up against the same issue and i'm starting to think about looking at the values of those two `UIImageView`s to figure out if its them or not. they do have a pretty unique signature:

```
<UIImageView: 0x8ab3e00; frame = (313 812.5; 7 3.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ab9740>>
<UIImageView: 0x8ab3e90; frame = (314.5 522; 3.5 341); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ab3f20>>
```

amongst other hooks that you could listen for. not ideal but not much in the way of options at this point...

heres an example. in this case, i was looping through the scrollview's subviews to figure out the optimal `contentSize` height for the scrollview based on the subviews when it started coming out with some funky values which lead me to think that it was the scrollbars that were screwing with me...

```
CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
for (UIView *view in self.myScrollView.subviews) {
    //exclude scroll bars, the width/height is 3.5 for non-retina or 7 
    //for retina. you can put some logic in here if you like to check
    //the appropriate 3.5/7.0 values for the respective screen densities
    if(view.frame.size.width > 7.0f && view.frame.size.height > 7.0f) {
        contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);
    }
}
container.contentSize = CGSizeMake(container.contentSize.width, contentRect.size.height);
```

if checking the frame of each UIView isn't specific enough for you, you could also ensure that it is a UIImageView.

i'm thinking this is the only "true" solution at this point. i'd personally rather not have to maintain another array of views.

**EDIT:**

here's my consolidated method that i use:

```
-(bool)isProbablyAScrollBar:(UIView*)view {
    CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    return (([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) && (view.frame.size.width <= (screenScale*3.5f) || view.frame.size.height <= (screenScale*3.5f)));
}
```

Comment: Neat idea, although hacky and could go wrong (but at least the method name suggests this). Just thought I'd comment with some improvements:
1. As well as checking the width, you could check that it's near the right (or height and near the bottom).
2. Frame is already measured in points so you should not multiply by the screen's scale.

Answer (score 0):

Are the scroll indicator views added and removed throughout the lifetime of the scroll view, or are they just added once and hidden and shown as necessary? If it's the latter, you could store your own references to them in init... instead of using the private ivars and proceed as you have tried to already.

Comment: Unfortunately not - they are added only when needed (i.e. when the user starts scrolling) and removed once they have disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

```
UIView* MYContentView=[[UIView alloc] initWithRect: CGrectMake:(0,0,Scrollview.frame.size.width, scrollview.frame.size.height)];

[ScrollView addsubview: MYContentView];
```

Then i added all the images to the MYContentView and later Rescaled the MYContentView and

```
  [ScrollView setContentSize:Cgsize];
```

Now you can Enumerate all Images in the MYContentView without worrying about the scrollbars.

Doing:

```
while ([[MYContentView subviews] count]>0) {
    [[[MYContentView subviews]lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Removed only the images. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Based on MrTristan's method. I think he mistakenly multiplied with screen scale.

```
+ (NSArray <UIView *> *)reservedSubviewsInUIScrollView:(UIScrollView *)view
{
    BOOL (^isProbablyAScrollBar)(UIView *s) = ^BOOL(UIView *s) {
        return [s isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && (s.frame.size.width <= 3.5 || s.frame.size.height <= 3.5);
    };

    NSMutableArray <UIView *> *reserved = [NSMutableArray new];
    for(UIView *s in view.subviews)
    {
        if(isProbablyAScrollBar(s))
        {
            [reserved addObject:s];
        }
    }
    return reserved;
}
```